# Java Spring Boot w/ MongoDB -- Not All Document Fields Are Being Mapped to POJO

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a MongoDB database populated with JSON files that represent game assets.

Here are the two JSON documents referenced in the example below:

```
{
  "name": "Kaelyssa, The Night's Whisper",
  "edition": 3,
  "revision": "2021 v1",
  "keywords": [
    "Retribution",
    "Mage Hunter",
    "Warcaster"
  ],
  "warjack points": 29,
  "field allowance": "C",
  "models": [
    {
         // SUB-DOCUMENT CONTAINING LOTS OF IRRELEVANT INFORMATION OMITTED FOR READABILITY
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "Mortitheurge Willbreaker",
  "edition": 3,
  "revision": "2021 v1",
  "keywords": [
    "Skorne",
    "Solo"
  ],
  "point cost": 2,
  "field allowance": 2,
  "models": [
    {
         // SUB-DOCUMENT CONTAINING LOTS OF IRRELEVANT INFORMATION OMITTED FOR READABILITY
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the model class relevant to the question (boilerplate code like getters, setters, and imports are omitted for readability):

```
@Document("cards")
public class Card {

    private ObjectId id;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "edition")
    private Integer edition;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "revision")
    private String revision;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "keywords")
    private ArrayList<String> keywords;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "unit size")
    private String unitSize;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "warjack points")
    private Integer warjackPoints;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "warbeast points")
    private Integer warbeastPoints;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "point cost")
    private Integer pointCost;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "field allowance")
    private String fieldAllowance;
    
    @BsonProperty(value = "models")
    private ArrayList<Model> models;
}
```

Here is my minimal Repository class:

```
public interface CardRepository extends MongoRepository<Card, String>{

    @Query("{name:'?0'}")
    Card findCardByName(String name);
    
    public long count();
}
```

Here is my application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GameApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    CardRepository cardRepository;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CollegeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        findCard();
    }   

    public void findCard() {
        long count = cardRepository.count();
        System.out.println("Number of cards found: " + count);

        String cardName = "Kaelyssa, The Night's Whisper";
        Card card = cardRepository.findCardByName(cardName);
        System.out.println(card);

        cardName = "Mortitheurge Willbreaker";
        card = cardRepository.findCardByName(cardName);
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my output when I run the application:

```
Number of cards found: 1209
Card [id=640f7ae7d0371a1460ba8e7f, name=Kaelyssa, The Night's Whisper, edition=3, revision=2021 v1, keywords=[Retribution, Mage Hunter, Warcaster], unitSize=null, warjackPoints=null, warbeastPoints=null, pointCost=null, fieldAllowance=null, models=[com.kriegzeug.college.com.model.Model@661e279d]]
Card [id=640f7ae9b608c31e106c5097, name=Mortitheurge Willbreaker, edition=3, revision=2021 v1, keywords=[Skorne, Solo], unitSize=null, warjackPoints=null, warbeastPoints=null, pointCost=null, fieldAllowance=null, models=[com.kriegzeug.college.com.model.Model@621624b1]]
```

As you can see, my application is mostly wired correctly.

I get the correct output of the `cardRepository.count()` method, and the `cardRepository.findCardByName()` method does retrieve the correct document.

What I'm not understanding is why the fields `name`, `edition`, `revision`, and `keywords`, and `models` are all being mapped correctly, but the fields `unitSize`, `warjackPoints`, `warbeastPoints`, `pointCost`, and `fieldAllowance` are all returning `null`, even when a value is present for that field. Note that one document has a `point cost` field while the other does not, one document has a `warjack points` field while the other does not and both documents have a `field allowance` field.

There might be a clue in that the non-populating fields all have keys in the JSON document that are two words separated by a space (e.g. "field allowance"). But shouldn't the `@BsonProperty(value = "field allowance")` annotation account for that?

Can anyone offer me a clue as to why my MongoDB documents aren't mapping correctly to my Java POJOs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the `@Field()` annotation in place of the `@BsonProperty()` annotation.

I don't know *why* `@Field` works when `@BsonProperty` doesn't, so if anyone can explain it to me, I'd still appreciate an answer.